# Em que consistem as listas de inicialização de membros e em que circunstancias devem ser utilizadas?

Tags: c++, classes, construtor, inicialização

Para que serve uma lista de inicialização de membros que é usada nos construtores de classes/structs na linguagem C++ e em quais circunstâncias devem ser utilizadas.